# lstlisting border bug when breaking lines

Tags: listings, color, framed

I have a certain bug regarding `listings`. I have used the `\lstset` command to configure my `lstlisting` environment.

Somehow, when I have a line that is too long to fit into one row the listing breaks it properly, but somehow the border gets the same colour as the font.

[image]

Here is the `\lstset`:

```
\lstnewenvironment{pascalCode}[1][]
{
  \lstset{  
    backgroundcolor=\color{lightgrey},
    breaklines=true,
    basicstyle=\footnotesize,
    keywordstyle=\color{Blue},
    commentstyle=\color{DarkGreen}\textit,
    numbers=left,
    numberstyle=\footnotesize,
    stringstyle=\color{red},
    showspaces = false,
    showstringspaces = false,
    tabsize = 2,
    %numbers=left,
    %numbersyle=\tiny
    frame=single,
    xleftmargin=5pt,
    xrightmargin=3pt,
    language =  Pascal,
    aboveskip = 20pt,
    #1
  }
}{}
```

If you have any ideas how to fix that please reply.

Comment: Is this really a bug - or a feature?

Comment: i'd prefere a black border over a colored one...

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It is considered a lot better to put in some code that will compile, as it makes it a lot easier for us to copy it into our text editor and work with it, and see exactly what it is you are trying to do.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Using the option `rulecolor=\color{black}` fixes that.  Here is a *before* and *after* comparison:

[image][image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}

\lstnewenvironment{pascalCode}[1][]
{
  \lstset{  
    backgroundcolor=\color{gray!40},
    breaklines=true,
    basicstyle=\footnotesize,
    keywordstyle=\color{blue},
    commentstyle=\color{green}\textit,
    numbers=left,
    numberstyle=\footnotesize,
    stringstyle=\color{red},
    showspaces = false,
    showstringspaces = false,
    tabsize = 2,
    %numbers=left,
    %numbersyle=\tiny
    frame=single,
    xleftmargin=5pt,
    xrightmargin=3pt,
    language =  Pascal,
    aboveskip = 20pt,
    rulecolor=\color{black},
    #1
  }
}{}

\begin{document}
\begin{pascalCode}
(*
Some really long line that takes more than one line so lstlistings needs to wrap this line.
*)
\end{pascalCode}
\end{document}
```