# Problems customizing listings captions

Tags: listings, color, captions

I'm trying to "decorate" source code with [`listings`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/listings), but I'm getting some warnings and bad boxes when I compile my document. However the document compiles and looks like I want.

I noticed the warning is due to some `}` and `{` symbols in the code.

> Overfull `\hbox` (6.0pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 31--31
>   [][][][][][][]   []
>
> LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for OMS+cmss on input
>   line 32.
>
> LaTeX Font Info:    No file OMScmss.fd. on input line 32.
>
> LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `OMS/cmss/m/n' undefined (Font)
>
>   using`OMS/cmsy/m/n' instead (Font)              for symbol
>   `textbraceleft' on input line 32.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[spanish,activeacute]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{caption}

\lstset{
basicstyle=\footnotesize,
numbers=left,
numberstyle=\tiny,
frame=tb,
columns=fullflexible,
showstringspaces=false
}


\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}  %this is because default font looks blurry

\DeclareCaptionFont{white}{\color{white}}
\DeclareCaptionFormat{listing}{\colorbox{black}{\parbox{\textwidth}{#1#2#3}}}
\captionsetup[lstlisting]{format=listing,labelfont=white,textfont=white}

\begin{document}

Some Code:
\begin{lstlisting}[caption=some code, label=source, language=java]
public void hello() {
    aaaa();
}
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the Cork encoding:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[spanish,activeacute]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{caption}

\lstset{
basicstyle=\footnotesize,
numbers=left,
numberstyle=\tiny,
frame=tb,
columns=fullflexible,
showstringspaces=false
}


\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}  %this is because default font looks blurry

\DeclareCaptionFont{white}{\color{white}}
\DeclareCaptionFormat{listing}{\colorbox{black}{\parbox{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\fboxsep\relax}{#1#2#3}}}
\captionsetup[lstlisting]{format=listing,labelfont=white,textfont=white}

\begin{document}

Some Code:
\begin{lstlisting}[caption=some code, label=source, language=java]
public void hello() {
    aaaa();
}
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

I also fixed an overfull box (you didn't have into account the `\fboxsep` lengths introduced by the `\colorbox`).

[image]

Perhaps you could be interested in [`this answer`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/128141/3954) from **Axel Sommerfeldt** (the author of `caption`) about \DeclareCaptionBox.

Comment: Great!. By the way, all this kind of stuff need to be done by hand?, there isnt some visual editor to design or something similar?. I ask you this because I started using latex few days ago, and every day I spend hours to customize the document to mi needs.

Comment: @Wyvern666 not that I know of.

Comment: BTW: The `caption` stuff (three lines of code) can be reduced to the single line `\captionsetup[lstlisting]{box=colorbox,boxcolor=black,font={color=white},slc=off}`, at least since `caption` v3.3. (`colorbox` takes account of `\fboxsep`.)